# how can I "unwrap" JSON arrays stored in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

i've got a postgresql database with a json column in it, along with some normal columns.

the json column stores an array of objects, like this:

```
[
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "EYR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "CCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "VCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}
]
```

i'd like to do a `SELECT` query on this table that breaks down the arrays so that each one is its own row, like:

```
| status  | register  | start_date   |
--------------------------------------
| "REGD"  | "EYR"     | "2008-09-01" |
| "REGD"  | "CCR"     | "2008-09-01" |
| "REGD"  | "VCR"     | "2008-09-01" |
```

how might i do this? i've experimented with the operators `->>` and `->`, but i don't see an easy way to unwrap arrays like this.

it looks like some of postgres' [json functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) will help, but i'm struggling to apply them to this situation.

mongodb has an [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation. i think i'm looking for something similar (edited)

---

**update:** i have something using `json_array_elements`, but i'm still struggling to unpack each key into its own column.

this doesn't quite work:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_elements(registers) AS register
    register->>'register' AS register_name

FROM items
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, json_array_elements(). I also included a CAST(), but that's up to you:

```
SELECT  j->>'status'
    ,   j->>'register'
    ,   CAST(j->>'start_date' AS date)
FROM    json_array_elements('
[
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "EYR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "CCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "VCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}
]'::json) s(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `mytable` CTE mimics your existing table with `another_column` for illustration.

```sql
with mytable(another_column, j) as 
(
 select 'other values', 
 '[
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "EYR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "CCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}, 
   {"status": "REGD", "register": "VCR", "start_date": "2008-09-01"}
 ]'::json
)
select another_column, 
       jae ->> 'status' status,
       jae ->> 'register' register,
       jae ->> 'start_date' start_date 
  from mytable 
 cross join lateral json_array_elements(j) jae;
```